# Bicep role assignment to storage account in different resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-rbac

I have a devops pipeline that run a "resource group" scoped deployment via "az deployment group create". There is no permission to run deployments at subscription level.

My bicep deploys a function app into resource group A. Resource group B contains an existing storage account. I'd like my bicep to create a role assignment on the existing storage account of blob data reader for the new function app.

I've created a dedicated module to apply the role assignment, as seen below:

```json
param environment string = 'dev'
param funcAppPrincipalId string
param stroageAcRG string

var storageAcName = 'storcats${environment}001'

var storageBlobDataReaderRole = subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1')

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' existing = {
  name: storageAcName
  scope: resourceGroup(stroageAcRG)
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(storageAccount.id, funcAppPrincipalId, storageBlobDataReaderRole)
  scope: storageAccount
  properties: {
    principalId: funcAppPrincipalId
    roleDefinitionId: storageBlobDataReaderRole
  }
}
```

My problem is, this gives a compile error on the line "scope: storageAccount":

> "A resource's scope must match the scope of the Bicep file for it to be deployable. You must use modules to deploy resources to a different scope.",

Comment: you need to use a module for that, you cant deploy resources to a different scope without a module

Comment: The error message also suggest that but I don’t know how.

Comment: Refer the scope mentioned in this document that has a storage account example -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/scope-extension-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @4c74356b41 for pointing me to a helpful doc on learn.microsoft.com.

The trick is to use the "scope" keyword when calling the module from main.bicep.

My main.bicep now contains the following:

```json
module roleAsForCats 'roleAssignmentForCatsBlob.bicep' = {
  name: 'roleAsForCats'
  scope: resourceGroup('rg-cats-${environment}-001')
  params: {
    funcAppPrincipalId: functionApp.outputs.appServicePrincipalId 
    environment: environment
  }
}
```

and the content of the module is:

```json
param environment string = 'dev'
param funcAppPrincipalId string

var storageAcName = 'storcats${environment}001'
var storageBlobDataReaderRole = subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1')

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' existing = {
  name: storageAcName
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-08-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(storageAccount.id, funcAppPrincipalId, storageBlobDataReaderRole)
  scope: storageAccount
  properties: {
    principalId: funcAppPrincipalId
    roleDefinitionId: storageBlobDataReaderRole
  }
}
```